# Oracle JSON parsing, 19c - Can't get nesting to work

Tags: json, oracle19c

I have the following JSON stored in a BLOB and after reading through the Oracle documentation on json_table, nested within a select, and dot notation I cannot figure out the best way to get at my data.

```
{       "filters": [
            {
                "system": "Givex",
                "target_document": "timepunch",
                "type": "EXCLUSION",
                "key": "job_codes",
                "value": "MANAGER",
                "description": ""
            },
            {
                "system": "Givex",
                "target_document": "menumix",
                "type": "EXCLUSION",
                "key": "plu_list",
                "value": "4,3,5,6,3,22",
                "description": ""
            }
        ],
        "toggles": [
            {
                "system": "Givex",
                "target_document": "salesmix",
                "type": "",
                "key": "use_category_not_sub",
                "value": "true",
                "description": "Will group sales by category not subcategory"
            }
        ]
,
        "cross_references": [
            {
                "system": "Givex",
                "target_document": "salesmix",
                "type": "",
                "key": "GL_MAP",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "gl_code": "2310",
                        "txn_name": "AB GST",
                        "txn_type_id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "2310",
                        "txn_name": "AB GST",
                        "txn_type_id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "1050-1",
                        "txn_name": "AMEX",
                        "txn_type_id": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "1005",
                        "txn_name": "Actual Cash On Hand",
                        "txn_type_id": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "4110",
                        "txn_name": "Appetizers",
                        "txn_type_id": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "2310",
                        "txn_name": "BC GST",
                        "txn_type_id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "2371",
                        "txn_name": "BC PST",
                        "txn_type_id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "2371",
                        "txn_name": "BC PST (10%)",
                        "txn_type_id": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "gl_code": "4150",
                        "txn_name": "Banquets",
                        "txn_type_id": "0"
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            }
```

I am trying to get the output of the gl_code, txn_name, and txn_type_id in tabular format from the cross_references -->values array where the key is 'GL_MAP'

have tried the following

```
select jt.*
from ar_test art,
json_table(art.json_data,'$.cross_references[*]' columns (value path '$.value')) jt
```

Which yields nothing back,

```
select art.json_data.cross_references.value from ar_test art
```

which returns null

and

```
select j.* from 
ar_test art,
json_table(art.json_data, '$.cross_references' columns (nested value columns(gl_code,txn_name,txn_type_id))) j
```

which returns no results at all.

Any advise would be very helpful as I'm new to Oracle JSON and struggling a bit :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just needed a bit more time.

select j.* from
ar_test art,
json_table(art.json_data, '$.cross_references' columns (nested value[*] columns(gl_code,txn_name,txn_type_id))) j;